# Under what conditions can we say that two things are ontological distinct?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, aristotle

I am curious as to under what conditions we say that two things are ontologically distinct. My hunch is that we say two things are ontologically distinct if they differ in their essential properties. This is what Aristotle would say. Are there any contemporary discussions with respect to this issue? I would be grateful if you could direct me to them

Comment: Why only essential? Two otherwise identical rocks in different locations are already ontologically distinct. If they differ in *any* property, essential or accidental, they are distinct. Under Leibniz's principle of [identity of indiscernibles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/), this condition is also necessary, to be distinct two things must have at least *one* property that distinguishes them. However, Leibniz's principle is controversial, so, perhaps,  even less might do. See also [SEP, Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/).

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for your response. I thought the fact that two things are distinct does not imply that they are ontologically distinct. For example I'm distinct from you but I'm not ontologically distinct from you because both you and I fall under the genus of human.

Comment: That would make nothing "ontologically distinct" because any two things would fall under some common category.

Comment: @Conifold But according to Aristotle, being is not a category.

Comment: It does not have to be being, and your question is about contemporary discussions rather than Aristotle. But I doubt even Aristotle would restrict ontological distinctions to essential ones. Accidents are also part of being.

Comment: @Conifold Can you tell me a little bit more?

Comment: Given your discussion with @Conifold it sounds like by "ontologically distinct" you mean that objects fall into natural categories and that two objects are ontologically distinct if they fall into different natural categories. Is that right?

Comment: @DavidGudeman Maybe if I clarified the question I was thinking about, It would be clearer what I'm looking for. I am thinking about the relationship between soul and body in Aristotle. And my guess is that soul and body are ontologically distinct from each other. They are ontologically distinct from each other in the virtue of the fact that one can act independently of the other. For example, when I'm thinking I can think without using any of my body parts and so on

Comment: @DavidGudeman But I'm interested in any clue you can give me with respect to the discussion of ontological distinction within the contemporary framework that can shed some light into the deficiencies of Aristotelian view

Comment: Then you would do well to start with the article on identity that Conifold told you about, and also the article on [Ordinary Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ordinary-objects/).

Comment: @DavidGudeman thank you